# Nuxt 3 scrollBehavior – scroll to hash urls, after page transition finishes, when the primary scrolling page element is not the root

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

My app does not use the document/body as the scrolling body, it uses a custom div with id `#overflow` as the primary scrolling element for each page. The reason for this is to make use of 3D transforms for parallax and various other transitional features, but I won't get into the details of this.  **So please accept that not using overflow on the root is required for my use case.**

Because I'm not using the root as my scrolling element, default router scroll links to hash URLs – such as `/some-page#some-hash` do not work. So, I need to override the default scroll behaviour so that any hash URLs for elements with matching IDs on the page are caught and appropriately scrolled to. However, I can't seem to get this working. I have tried multiple different approaches:

Using the page:finish hook in a plugin:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.hook('page:finish', () => {
    const overflow = document.getElementById("overflow");
    const hash = window.location.hash;
    if (overflow) {
      if (hash) {
        const section = document.getElementById(hash.replace('#',''));
        const distance = section ? section.getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY - 120 : null;
        overflow.scrollTo({top: distance, behavior: 'smooth'});
      } else {
        overflow.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  })
})
```

overriding scrollBehavior and awaiting the elements to be found on the page in an async function in a plugin:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.$router.options.scrollBehavior = async (to, from, savedPosition) => {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    }

    const findEl = async (hash, x = 0) => {
      return (
        document.querySelector(hash) ||
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (x > 0) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector("#overflow"));
          }
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(findEl(hash, 1));
          }, 100);
        })
      );
    };

    const overflow = await document.getElementById("overflow");
    if (overflow) {
      if (to.hash) {
        const el = await findEl(to.hash);
        //const distance = el ? el.getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY - 120 : null;
        const distance = el ? el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 120 : null;
        console.log(distance);
        if ("scrollBehavior" in overflow.style) {
          return el.scrollTo({ top: 400, behavior: "smooth" });  // everything above works but just doesn't action the final scroll function   
         }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

using onAfterEnter event in global page transitions in nuxt.config:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    pageTransition: {
      name: 'page',
      mode: 'out-in',
      onAfterEnter: () => {
        const hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
          const section = document.getElementById(hash.replace('#',''));
          const overflow = document.getElementById('overflow');
          const distance = section ? section.getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY - 120 : null;
          if (section && distance) {
            overflow.scrollTo({top: distance, behavior: 'smooth'});
          }
          
        }
      }
      //duration:{ enter: 1000, leave: 800 }
    },
}
});
```

in the mounted hook on an on page component which is rendered after the page transitions are complete.

```
onMounted(() => {
const overflow = document.getElementById("overflow");
    const hash = window.location.hash;
    if (overflow) {
      if (hash) {
        const section = document.getElementById(hash.replace('#',''));
        const distance = section ? section.getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY - 120 : null;
        overflow.scrollTo({top: distance, behavior: 'smooth'});
      } else {
        overflow.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

})
```

None of the above attempts work. Does anyone have an alternative solution?

Comment: How does it not work? Are there errors? Does it fail to find the elements? Does it not scroll?